# How to prevent the crash of QGIS a plugin if getOpenFileName() dosent work?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am writing a QGIS plugin (for QGIS3), where I am trying to allow the user to open a filename via the getOpenFileName() function. It works fine when the user selects a file, but if he dont (click close or cancel button in the open file dialog) then the entire QGIS application crashes.

I had tried to prevent this with the try/error function, but it still dont help me preventing the crash.

I have the following code:

```
import qgis
import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QMessageBox
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QProgressBar, QProgressDialog
try:
    filename5 = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()[0] #Here the program risks to crash
except:
    QMessageBox.information(None, 'Error', 'Error')
self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(filename5)
self.iface.addVectorLayer(filename5, 'Lithsamp', 'ogr')
```

Answer (score 0):

The try/except isn't catching anything because there never is any error. When the user cancels the dialog, `filename5` will just be an empty string. Instead you can use a if/else statement.

```
filename5 = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()[0]
if filename5:
    self.dlg.lineEdit.setText(filename5)
    self.iface.addVectorLayer(filename5, 'Lithsamp', 'ogr')
else:
    QMessageBox.information(None, 'Error', 'Error')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should test the lenght of returned path

```
fpath, filters = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
if len(fpath) > 0:
    do_stuff
```